# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade does not find latest kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, upgrade

I have an 18.04 host,A, currently running the 4.15.0-124-generic kernel.

The latest is 4.15.0-126-generic.

host A had holds on linux-generic, linux-headers-generic, linux-image-generic so the kernel wouldn't change and mess up the nvidia drivers manually installed from Nvidia. This was done because researchers needed that stability.

I removed the holds, ran apt update, apt upgrade and it the new kernel isn't "found".

I compared the /etc/apt/sources.list files to host B and they have identical hosts.

They are both calling the same repos for the kernel updates, but A isn't "seeing" them.

Additional things tried:

apt clean

checked apt-cache policy for all linux images there and no luck

Comment: Have you installed a recent hardware enablement stack? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: We have not. We are sticking with the 4 kernel for these hosts.

Comment: I tried to update a host and somehow, somewhere the latest kernel was found and installed.

No clue what changed or how.

I hate these heisenbugs.